# How can I cache GraphQL requests with VueJS and GraphQL-Yoga

Tags: vue.js, caching, graphql

I have a Vue2 app which grabs data from my GraphQL backend. Think User count, Posts made, your Posts and things like that.

The HTML, CSS, JS etc of the Vue2 app is on a CDN and loads very quickly. The GraphQL server, my own, is located in one location and can load slowly if you're far away from the server. I want to increase my site's loading times.

How can I form a kind of CDN for my GraphQL layer that caches results in various locations so that common requests are snappy and fast. I have a rough idea on how I might begin doing this but I still feel I am in need of existing services/frameworks for guidance or direct use.

I have heard of GraphCool and Hasura, are these things I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options at your disposal:

- Use AWS with location-based Routing and multi-region EC2 instances. For the most reliable and fastest service, you should have an instance in the following locations: Northern California (USA), Northern Virginia (USA), Sao Paulo (Brazil), Paris (France), Mumbai (India), Hong Kong (China), Tokyo (Japan), Singapore, Sydney (Australia). You can use a `free ec2 instance` in all of these zones and pay next to to nothing yearly while you're getting started, and scale them up as you need. I recommend the `t3 micro`, which is one of the absolute cheapest solutions you can get. This will run you approximately $840 for the year.
- Move over to Heroku, which basically allows you to do the exact same thing I've outlined above in AWS, with less overall total control.
- Use `Vuex` to store the results in `localStorage` on the users computer by combining `Vuex` with the power of a persistent storage plugin, like [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate). Combine this with `server sent events` to avoid ever having to make a request for updated information outside of the initial request you make. *Note*: This will not solve the initial slow load up-front.
- Ignore `Vuex` all together and just store the result on the client side in localStorage and fetch it whenever you'd like. *Note*: This will not solve the initial slow load up-front.

### Why haven't you mentioned Hasura yet?!

Hasura its self is not a cloud-service that works stand alone. Instead, Hasura allows you to drop in a `GraphQL Engine` on top of a pre-existing `PostgreSQL` database.